# Keyboard shortcut for switching lenses

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, lenses

It used to be that I could switch to another lens by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button in 11.10 but it seems that the key has been mapped to focusing different sections of the same lens in 12.04.

Is there a new shortcut assigned to switching lenses in 12.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out.

- It's now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.