# How can I change the keyboard shortcut to switch lenses?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lenses

The keyboard shortcut to change lenses in 12.04 has changed from being <kbd>Tab</kbd> to being: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. As answered in this question: [Keyboard shortcut for switching lenses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118066/keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-lenses)

I can see that this was probably done to improve navigation as you can now choose which direction you want to navigate through the lenses, however I'm a bit stuck in my ways and would like to know if the behaviour can be switched back so that just <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches lenses.

Answer (score 2):

These key combinations are hardcoded into the Unity plug-in for Compiz and are not exposed as options that can be changed through a configuration setting. To change them, you would need to recompile your own version of Unity.